# Elasticsearch stats aggregation group by date on timeseries

Tags: elasticsearch, time-series, aggregation

I having some trouble getting a query working.  I want to aggregate a weather station's timeseries data in ElasticSearch. I have a value (double) for each day of the year.  I would like a query to be able to provide me the sum, min, max of my value field, grouped by month.

My document has a stationid field and a timeseries object array:

}`PUT /stations/rainfall/2
{
   "stationid":"5678",
   "timeseries": [
      {
         "value": 91.3,
         "date": "2016-05-01"
      },
      {
         "value": 82.2,
         "date": "2016-05-02"
      },
      {
         "value": 74.3,
         "date": "2016-06-01"
      },
      {
         "value": 34.3,
         "date": "2016-06-02"
      }
   ]
}`

So I am hoping to be able to query this stationid: "5678" or the doc index:2 
and see: stationid: 5678, monthlystats: [ month:5, avg:x, sum:y, max:z ]

Many thanks in advance for any help.  Also happy to take any advice on my document structure too.

Comment: Your `timeseries` field need to be mapped as a [`nested` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), is this the case?

Comment: Hi @Val, yep that's the case.  I configured the timeseries object in the document to be nested

Comment: 'PUT /stations
{
   "mappings": {
      "rainfall": {
         "properties": {
            "stationid":{"type": "string"}
            , "timeseries": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "date": { "type": "date"}, 
                  "value":{"type": "double"}
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'